# Is VBScripting disabled in Office 365 update?

Tags: excel, office365

Recently Microsoft published that they will be disabling the VBScripting in office client application?
Has this been completely done? In case yes, Is there a way out to run vbscripting via other root?

-Thanks
Ankur

Comment: Have a look at this: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Registry-key-to-re-enable-835fba77

Comment: Thanks!! Netloh. Is there any alternative available to vbscripting?